# I'm using the Requests module to login into Instagram and retrieve user information after login in

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

EDIT: Code works now, problem was to do with Non-ASCII character '\xe2', 
solved by declaring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I referred to [PEP-263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for help.

---

I'm login into instagram using requests using this code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'ajax/'

headers_list = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101"
" Firefox/41.0"


USERNAME = 'myUser'
PASSWD = 'myPassword'
USER_AGENT = headers_list

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
session.headers.update({'Referer': BASE_URL})
req = session.get(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find('body')

pattern = re.compile('window._sharedData')
script = body.find("script", text=pattern)

script = script.get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]
data = json.loads(script)

csrf = data['config'].get('csrf_token')
login_data = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWD}
session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': csrf})
login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
print(login.content)

# b'{"authenticated": true, "user": true, "userId": "*******", "oneTapPrompt": false, "status": "ok"}'
```

However, once I've logged in I want to extract user info e.g. `n` number of followers & posts. I've got this code that gives the information of a specific user.

```
html = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/USER')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
item = soup.select_one("meta[property='og:description']")
name = item.find_previous_sibling().get("content").split("•")[0]
followers = item.get("content").split(",")[0]
following = item.get("content").split(",")[1].strip()
print(f'{name}\n{followers}\n{following}')
```

But what I want is to display the logged user info rather than a specific account. How would I go about it?

Comment: Did your code working normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply visit your own page while logged in.

This modification should do the trick:

```
html = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+USERNAME)
```